# .NET Generic classes within IOptions with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, appsettings

I'm trying to setup generic classes within IOptions settings.
Example:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IMyClass
{
   public MyClass(IOption<MyOptions<T>> options)
   {
   
   }
}
```

To be able to dynamically use settings from appsettings.json. While the set of options is the same, they should be under different schemas, so that each type defines its set of options i.e.:

```
"MyOptionsForClass1":
{
   "Option1" : 1,
   "Option2" : 1
},
"MyOptionsForClass2":
{
   "Option1" : 2,
   "Option2" : 2
},
```

And the options classes should look like this:

```
public class MyOptions<T>
{
   public const string ConfigSchemaName = "DefaultOptions"
   public int Option1 {get; set;}
   public int Option2 {get; set;}
}

public class OptionsForClass1 : MyOptions<MyClass1>
{
   public new const string ConfigSchemaName = "MyOptionsForClass1"
   public int Option1 {get; set;}
   public int Option2 {get; set;}
}
```

And then in ConfigureServices to add something like:

```
.AddScoped<MyOptions<MyClass1>, OptionsForClass1>();
...

.AddOptions<MyOptions<MyClass1>>()
.Bind(configuration.GetSection(OptionsForClass1.ConfigSchemaName);
```

Is this how this should be done?
Are there any other more clean approaches for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Whenever you use `new` to shadow a member of the class like that you're opening yourself up to pain.

Comment: You cannot override a const/static member of a base class. You can only shadow it and then it begins to fail. I've posted an answer that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should not do it this way.

[image: OptionsForClass1]

Note the squiggly lines under `Option1` and `Option2`? It's telling you that you are hiding the members in the parent class, but you forgot to use the `new` keyword.

But using `new` is bad for hiding (shadowing) members. Try this code:

```
var ofc1 = new OptionsForClass1();
ofc1.Option1 = 42;
Console.WriteLine(ofc1.Option1);
var my = (MyOptions<MyClass1>)ofc1;
Console.WriteLine(my.Option1);
```

That outputs:

```
42
0
```

Note that I've only created one instance of `OptionsForClass1` but when I cast to `MyOptions<MyClass1>` I get a different value for `Option1`.

Your approach kills the value of inheritance.

If you do want this kind of structure, your code should look like this:

```
public class MyOptions<T>
{
    public virtual string ConfigSchemaName => "DefaultOptions";
    public virtual int Option1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int Option2 { get; set; }
}

public class OptionsForClass1 : MyOptions<MyClass1>
{
    public override string ConfigSchemaName => "MyOptionsForClass1";
}
```

---

You could avoid a `const string` by using an attribute.

Try this:

```
public class ConfigSchemaNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public ConfigSchemaNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}


[ConfigSchemaName("MyOptionsForClass1")]
public class OptionsForClass1 : MyOptions<MyClass1>
{
    
}
```

Then you can write this:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    typeof(OptionsForClass1)
        .GetCustomAttribute<ConfigSchemaNameAttribute>()
        .Name);
```

That outputs:

```
MyOptionsForClass1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely use it.

But, do you see it as a viable solution? Isn't there something simpler to achieve the goal.
Unfortunately, I didn't find anything similar while searching on the internet, but the case does not sound like ultra-rare

Comment: in this case I wouldn't be able to access ConfigSchemaName  in ConfigureServices, as it won't be conts/static anymore.

Comment: @IgorRailean - Why not use `typeof(OptionsForClass1).Name`? Or an attribute? It appears the only reason you're using a `const string` is to get a static value.

Comment: @IgorRailean - I've shown you how to use an attribute.

Comment: I can indeed try to use the name of type, or, if I need something more configurable -> an attribute.

Something like:
.AddOptions<MyOptions<MyClass1>>()
.Bind(configuration.GetSection(typeof(MyClass1).Name);
  

  But it will anyway require that trick with
```
.AddScoped<MyOptions<MyClass1>, OptionsForClass1>();
```

Is this something ok?

Comment: @IgorRailean - I don't know the specifics of the DI you're using.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this how this should be done?

It's definitely how it *can* be done. Should be done? That's pretty subjective, once the solution meets a certain standard of quality.

Your solution falls into the over-engineered category, where you have a very intricate solution to a problem that has simpler solutions. For example, you could have a simple dictionary of settings you inject in every object, and each object takes out what settings it wants. Very simple and efficient, both at run-time and while coding -- no boilerplate at all, one class for all cases!

But if you have *a lot* of options, maybe you need the over-engineered solution. There's definitely nothing wrong with it, besides it being over-engineered. Though I'd suggest separate settings files if you have such an incredible amount of settings that you need separate classes for all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

The idea is to be able to inject options dynamically and not to do anything in MyClass<T> class.

If I use the dictionary with Options, how do I know, which options do I need for a specific Type?
Or you mean dict, when type is key and value is schemaName from appsettings, so we can explicitly query serviceCollection for required service?

Comment: "how do I know, which options do I need for a specific Type" -- I'm not sure I follow, isn't it you who's writing the consumers of these options? Because if it's not, then ask whoever is writing them what options they're using, if that's something really important to you.

Comment: The idea is to consume them in MyClass dynamically. So MyClass does not have to decide which set of options to take.

Comment: When you say `MyClass`, you mean `MyOptions`? If so then my point is that you don't need to split, you can have your settings repository load *every* setting and the consumers can pick and choose what they need. If you actually mean `MyClass`, ie the consumer as per your apparent naming conventions, then I still don't follow. If this is the case your code seems schizophrenic, unable to know what it needs to run.

Comment: MyClass<T> is a generic class. It has to accept a set of IOptions in constructor,
.These IOptions must be different for each class T. So, it somehow needs to know how to map specific type T to a proper IOptions instance.

Use case was described in the first message:  

```
"MyOptionsForClass1":
{
   "Option1" : 1,
   "Option2" : 1
},
"MyOptionsForClass2":
{
   "Option1" : 2,
   "Option2" : 2
},
```  

Here, for example MyClass<MyClass1> needs MyOptionsForClass1
and another MyClass<MyClass2> needs MyOptionsForClass2

Comment: "These IOptions must be different for each class T" -- no they don't, you just did it that way. And your question asks if that's the best way to do it. The answer is "it depends", and it certainly isn't the *only* way to do it. Try typing that comment again, but replace "needs" with "I want" to get an idea of the difference.

Comment: In fact, the only hard requirement of your question is, and I quote, "To be able to dynamically use settings from appsettings.json". Ie all your settings are already in a single file. You're just doing all this splitting in tons of little classes because you don't like something about just using settings, but you never really explain what that is.